# Error testing external API function with jest (react-query: useQuery)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-query

When using Jest to test a function I have that makes a call to external API I get an error about only being able to use a hooks inside of a functional component.

My function(useGetGophys) uses `useQuery` from `react-query` which is the hook.

I would like to be able to test the useGetGophy with jest please?

I am mocking the actual fetch request as can be seen in the test file code below.

[image: invalid hook call error]

useGetGophy.js

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import urlGenerator from "../utils/urlGenerator"

export default function useGetGophys({ query, limit }) {
    const url = urlGenerator({ query, limit })

    const { data, status } = useQuery(["gophys", { url }], async () => {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        return res.json()
    })

    return {
        status,
        data,
    }
}
```

Test file
useGetGophy.test.js

```
import useGetGophys from '../services/useGetGophys'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query"

const desiredDataStructure = [{
    id: expect.any(String),
    images: {
        fixed_width_downsampled: {
            url: expect.any(String),
            width: expect.any(String),
            height: expect.any(String),
        },
    },
    embed_url: expect.any(String),
    bitly_gif_url: expect.any(String),
    url: expect.any(String),
    title: expect.any(String),
}]

global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(desiredDataStructure)
    })
)

describe('getGetGophy - ', () => {
    test('returns correctly structured data', async () => {
        const gophys = useGetGophys('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?q=daniel&api_key=00000000&limit=15&rating=g')
        expect(gophys).toBe(desiredDataStructure)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to render your hook using `testing-library/react-hooks`. As long as you are returning an object, check for `result.current.data`, something like:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

test('returns correctly structured data', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetGophys('yourUrl'));
  expect(result.current.data).toEqual(desiredDataStructure);
});
```